# If statement doesn't take place

Tags: python, if-statement

I have been testing some my code and for some reason my if statement is being ignored.  The first if statement works but the second if statement doesn't, i have tried changing it to elif and it still doesn't work.  Thanks in advance.

```
import random


diff = input("What is the ritual difficulty? ")
level = input("How many ritual levels do you have that pertain to this ritual? ")

bag = []

for success in xrange(10):
    bag.append("Success")

bag.append("Flaw")
bag.append("Fail")

extra = level - diff

if extra >= 1:
    extra = extra / 2

    int(extra)
    for chance in xrange(extra):
        bag.append("Success")

if extra < 0:   
    for chance in xrange(extra):
        bag.append("Flaw")
        bag.append("Fail")
        bag.append("Backlash")

print bag

random.shuffle(bag)

outcome = bag.pop()

print "The outcome of the ritual is: ", outcome
```

Comment: @Wooble he stated in his question that the 2nd if statement is the one being ignored.

Comment: if extra<0, then xrange(extra) will be empty

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I have never worked in python but if that is true that xrange will be empty if extra < 0 then that will mean that the for loop will exit out immediately making it look like the if statement is being ignored.

Comment: why not use range() instead of xrange()?

Answer (score 3):

You second `if` will be entered if the `diff` is larger than the `level`. However, even if it does get entered it won't actally do something:

```
if extra < 0:   
    for chance in xrange(extra):
        bag.append("Flaw")
        bag.append("Fail")
        bag.append("Backlash")
```

The `xrange` function will yield an empty "list" (it's not actually a list, as the [documentation for `xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) explains) for negative values, i.e. nothing will be appended to the bag.

Comment: (Presumably you want to fix this by using `xrange(-extra)`.

Comment: @Wooble Possibly, or maybe `extra / -2` (much like in the other `if`): I don't know enough about the obscure rituals performed here to be able to tell what's right and what's wrong. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not ignored, but when you run a `for` loop on `xrange(extra)` with `extra` being negative, then obviously this loop is immediately terminated.

P.S.: you might wanna try `xrange(-extra)` instead...